# Unable to see Selenium tests are running on the browser when the test is run by Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins

When I run the Selenium test from Eclipse I can be able to see that tests are running into a browser.

But when I run the test under Jenkins, I can not see that any thing or any kind of test are going on the browsers.

But when I look into the Jenkins console I can see that it is running all the test one after another and all the test, build are successful.

**My question is; why I am not able to see that my tests are running on the browsers when the test is running through Jenkins.**

Note:
- I am running Jenkins under http://localhost:8080
- Windows 7
- In all browsers

**Jenkins Console Output:**

```
Started by user anonymous
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson3274622619396434505.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace>"C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\nosvn.bat"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace>rmdir /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace\" 
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace>mkdir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace\" 
A subdirectory or file C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace\ already exists.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace>xcopy "C:\Selenium\workspace\SS" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace" /e 
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\.classpath
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\.project
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\build.xml
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\conditional-suite-build.xml
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\nosvn.bat
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\properties_build_clean_compile_report.xml
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\readme.txt
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\refactored-param-build.xml
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\selenium.properties
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\start_stop_selenium.xml
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\suite-build.xml
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\calculate\CalculateTwoNumbersMultipleTests.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\calculate\CalculateTwoNumbersTestsTabFile.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\cookies\CookieTests.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\htmlform\Chrome_only_form_tests.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\htmlform\HTML_form_tests.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\javascript\AjaxPageTests.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\pageObjectModel\BasicAjaxPage.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\pageObjectModel\BasicHTMLForm.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\pageObjectModel\CalculateForm.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\pageObjectModel\HTMLFormResultsPage.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\pageObjectModel\SearchPage.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\search\SearchPageTests.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\testClasses\SeleniumSimplifiedTest$1.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\testClasses\SeleniumSimplifiedTest.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\testSuites\AllTestsAnyBrowserTestSuite.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\testSuites\AllTestsChromeOrFirefoxBrowserTestSuite.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\testSuites\AnyBrowserTestsGroup.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\testSuites\ChromeOrFirefoxBrowserTestsGroup.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\testSuites\TestSuite.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumutils\seleniumManager\SeleniumManager.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\bin\com\eviltester\seleniumutils\seleniumManager\TheSeleniumManager.class
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\lib\junit-4.10.jar
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\lib\readme.txt
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-09-14\firefox_test_calculate_two_values_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-09-14\firefox_test_calculate_two_values_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-10-13\firefox_test_calculate_two_values_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-10-13\firefox_test_calculate_two_values_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-10-13\firefox_test_reverse_calculate_two_values_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-10-13\firefox_test_reverse_calculate_two_values_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_checkCookiesGetCreated_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_checkCookiesGetCreated_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_createCookieExplored_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_createCookieExplored_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_deleteCookieExplored_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_deleteCookieExplored_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_enterAnInvalidValueInBlurInputAndTriggerValidation_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_enterAnInvalidValueInBlurInputAndTriggerValidation_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_enterAnInvalidValueInBlurInput_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_enterAnInvalidValueInBlurInput_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_getCookieByNameExplored_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_getCookieByNameExplored_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_navigationTests_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_navigationTests_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_parseResultsOfGetCookieExplored_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_parseResultsOfGetCookieExplored_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_test_calculate_two_values_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_test_calculate_two_values_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_test_reverse_calculate_two_values_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_test_reverse_calculate_two_values_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_test_submit_form_without_clicking_submit_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_test_submit_form_without_clicking_submit_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_test_submit_form_with_default_values_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_test_submit_form_with_default_values_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_test_submit_form_with_new_details_SeleniumException_screenshot.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\screenshots\2011-12-19-13-55-20\firefox_test_submit_form_with_new_details_SeleniumException_screenshotfull.png
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\main\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\pageObjectModel\BasicAjaxPage.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\main\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\pageObjectModel\BasicHTMLForm.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\main\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\pageObjectModel\CalculateForm.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\main\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\pageObjectModel\HTMLFormResultsPage.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\main\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\pageObjectModel\SearchPage.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\main\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\testClasses\SeleniumSimplifiedTest.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\main\java\com\eviltester\seleniumutils\seleniumManager\SeleniumManager.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\main\java\com\eviltester\seleniumutils\seleniumManager\TheSeleniumManager.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\test\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\calculate\CalculateTwoNumbersMultipleTests.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\test\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\calculate\CalculateTwoNumbersTestsTabFile.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\test\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\cookies\CookieTests.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\test\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\htmlform\Chrome_only_form_tests.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\test\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\htmlform\HTML_form_tests.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\test\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\javascript\AjaxPageTests.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\test\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\search\SearchPageTests.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\test\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\testSuites\AllTestsAnyBrowserTestSuite.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\test\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\testSuites\AllTestsChromeOrFirefoxBrowserTestSuite.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\test\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\testSuites\AnyBrowserTestsGroup.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\test\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\testSuites\ChromeOrFirefoxBrowserTestsGroup.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\test\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\testSuites\TestSuite.java
C:\Selenium\workspace\SS\src\test\resources\datafiles\calculate2numbers.tab
89 File(s) copied
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '"ant.bat && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
Buildfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace\build.xml

clean:

makedir:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace\build
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace\junit-results
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace\junit-report

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 20 source files to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace\build
    [javac] Note: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace\src\main\java\com\eviltester\seleniumSimplified\testClasses\SeleniumSimplifiedTest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

all_selenium_tests:

run_param_junit_tests:
    [junit] Running com.eviltester.seleniumSimplified.calculate.CalculateTwoNumbersMultipleTests
    [junit] Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 11,633 sec
    [junit] Running com.eviltester.seleniumSimplified.calculate.CalculateTwoNumbersTestsTabFile
    [junit] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 8,053 sec
    [junit] Running com.eviltester.seleniumSimplified.cookies.CookieTests
    [junit] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 18,025 sec
    [junit] Running com.eviltester.seleniumSimplified.htmlform.Chrome_only_form_tests
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 8,444 sec
    [junit] Running com.eviltester.seleniumSimplified.htmlform.HTML_form_tests
    [junit] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 10,458 sec
    [junit] Running com.eviltester.seleniumSimplified.javascript.AjaxPageTests
    [junit] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 9,298 sec
    [junit] Running com.eviltester.seleniumSimplified.search.SearchPageTests
    [junit] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 6,863 sec

report-junit:
[junitreport] Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SS-Firefox\workspace\junit-report\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to C:\Windows\TEMP\null931835500
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/WinAnt/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] Transform time: 1228ms
[junitreport] Deleting: C:\Windows\TEMP\null931835500

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 21 seconds
Recording test results
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: can u give more info about your selenium server configuration? the selenium tests are run on selenium RC client and not on your browser, what is your configured selenium RC?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the bellow three files are used to configure the selenium server in my case: (http://www.copypastecode.com/155875/) (http://www.copypastecode.com/155882/) (http://www.copypastecode.com/155886/)

Answer (score 1):

You won't see the output because Jenkins is running your tests as a service in the background.

The fact that you're logged into the machine running Jenkins as the service doesn't mean that it will show the output there.

Comment: Is there anyway in which we can actually see the browser in action?

Comment: When I remote log in to the server with the same account set up for the service, I can't see the browser would be executed, however, the logs show that something had happened. [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834207/when-selenium-test-runs-by-jenkins-and-nunit-the-browser-doesnt-come-up-howeve)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jenkins service is run as system process. 
[image: Jenkins master process]

And what ever child processs it will spawn those will also run as system process only.
[image: Chrome process spawned by jenkins]

So you need to start jenkins from CMD and as User Process. Please find the same [Start jenkins from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869311/start-stop-and-restart-jenkins-service-on-windows)