# How to change port for jenkins window service when 8080 is being used

Tags: jenkins

I installed Jenkins on a windows virtual server and want to run it as window service.

Since the port 8080 is being used by other service, I changed the http port to 8081 in jenkins.xml file. However, I am not able to launch localhost:8081/jenkins at all.  I need detail instruction/steps to configure port 8081 or something to run Jenkins.

Comment: I follow the answer to change port to 8090 but Jenkins still runs at 8080 port. Anybody knows why? (note: I even clear Windows virtualstore files of my current account)

Answer (score 83):

1. Go to the directory where you installed Jenkins (by default, it's under Program Files/Jenkins)
2. Open the `Jenkins.xml` configuration file
3. Search `--httpPort=8080` and replace the `8080` with the new port number that you wish
4. Restart Jenkins for changes to take effect

Comment: I placed it to 8090 but it didt work, still open jenkins with 8080 port, Should I restart the server aswell?

Comment: The running instance of Jenkins does not see the changes done in this file.  They are only applied at startup time.

Comment: 4. To restart Jenkins, go to the directory Jenkins is installed(e.g.: C:/Program Files(x86)/Jenkins) via Command Prompt & type 'jenkins.exe restart' (without quotes of course). https://stackoverflow.com/a/14869398/8696237

Comment: You can restart the jenkins from url like "http://jenkins_host_url:port/restart" after Jenkins.xml is updated.

Answer (score 36):

#### Restart Jenkins service

Just **restart** the **Jenkins service** after you changed the port in **jenkins.xml**.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type "services.msc"
3. Right click on the "Jenkins" line > Restart

   [image: Restart Jenkins]
4. Type `http://localhost:8081/` in your browser to test the change.

Answer (score 35):

On **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** you can change the Port like that:

1. Change port number in the config file `/etc/default/jenkins` to 8081 (or the port you like) `HTTP_PORT=8081`
2. Restart Jenkins: `service jenkins restart`

Comment: Also needed to change the port in Dashboard: **`Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Jenkins URL`**  to  **8081**

Answer (score 34):

Start Jenkins from cmd line with this command :

`java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081`

Comment: That's not a windows service

Comment: thanks man. this is what i needed. did not want to run as service

Answer (score 19):

If you are running on Redhat, do following

1. Stop Jenkins
   `$sudo service jenkins stop`
2. change port number in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` like i did for port 8081
   `JENKINS_PORT="8081"`
3. start Jenkins again
   `$sudo service jenkins start`

## make sure your FW has correct burn rules.

Answer (score 11):

In linux,

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
```

set following configuration with any available port

```
JENKINS_PORT="8082"
```

Answer (score 5):

You should follow 2 steps:

1. This step can be followed by running the cmd in the specific folder location where there will be `.war` file. This step helpful as Jenkins needs some disk space to perform builds and keep archives.

   ```
   set JENKINS_HOME=c:\folder\Jenkins
   ```
2. This step will be helpful to change the port number, and works can be performed accordingly.

   ```
   java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8585
   ```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thanks, for the awareness mate, I've updated the comment that I've done. This might help now.

Answer (score 5):

##### Changing Jenkins Port (METHOD 1)

`sudo nano /etc/default/jenkins`

Scroll down until you find the following lines:

> # port for HTTP connector (default 8080; disable with -1)
>
> HTTP_PORT=8080

Edit the second line to include the port number you want to specify. For instance:

> HTTP_PORT=8081

Restart Jenkins:

`sudo systemctl restart jenkins`

##### Changing Jenkins Port (METHOD 2)

Populate /lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service with configuration parameters for the launch
To change jenkins port, set Jenkins to listen on port <PORT_NUMBER>:

Open systemd service file:
`sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service`

change port:

> [Service]
> Environment="JENKINS_PORT=9191"

Reload units:
`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Restart jenkins:
`sudo systemctl restart jenkins`

##### More info:

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#debianubuntu

Answer (score 4):

Check in Jenkins.xml and update like below

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8090</arguments>
```

Answer (score 3):

1 ) Open the **jenkins.xml** file 
2 ) Search for the **"--httpPort=8080"** Text and replace the port number 8080 with your custom port number (like 7070 , 9090 )
3 ) Go to your **services** running your machine & find out the **Jenkins service** and click on restart.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Use Default Port

If the default port 8080 has been bind with other process, Then kill that process.

```
DOS> netstat -a -o -n
```

Find the process id (PID) XXXX of the process which occupied 8080.

```
DOS> taskkill /F /PID XXXX
```

Now, start Jenkins (on default port)

```
DOS> Java -jar jenkins.war
```

### Use Custom Port

```
DOS> Java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8008
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to run Jenkins when the default port "8080" is already bind with other process.                                                                 Option-1: Kill the process which occupies 8080                                           Example: C:\Users\maris>netstat -a -n -o | find "8080"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2900
  TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       2900
C:\Users\maris>taskkill /PID 2900 /F
SUCCESS: The process with PID 2900 has been terminated.
C:\Users\maris>

Answer (score 2):

edit HTTP_PORT in config file:

```bash
sudo nano /etc/default/jenkins
# update
# HTTP_PORT=1234
# set any port you want
```

If this doesn't resolve the issue,
set the port in jenkins.service file:

```bash
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service
# update
# Environment="JENKINS_PORT=1234"
# set any port you want
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/override.conf
# update
# Environment="JENKINS_PORT=1234"
# set any port you want
```

Then restart the service by:

```bash
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart jenkins.service
# check status by:
sudo systemctl status jenkins.service
```

Note: to check if a port is available to use, run:

```bash
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 'port_number'
# no result will show if port_number is not being used.
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu there is a small change in paths etc:

First, you need to open the Jenkins config file:

Path for GUI:

```
/etc/default/jenkins
```

Command for terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/jenkins
```

Note: instead of nano you can use vi, cat, etc

find HTTP_PORT

replace 8080 to any port like:

```
HTTP_PORT=8282
```

Answer (score 0):

**On Windows (with Windows Service).**

Edit the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.xml with **8083** if you want 8083 port.

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8083</arguments>
```

Answer (score 0):

For jenkins in a docker container you can use port publish option in docker run command to map jenkins port in container to different outside port.

e.g. map docker container internal jenkins GUI port 8080 to port 9090 external

```
docker run -it -d --name jenkins42 --restart always \
   -p <ip>:9090:8080 <image>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that since Jenkins 2.332.1, this won't work anymore, as described in the accepted answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71710824/jenkins-not-picking-up-config-file-changed-etc-default-jenkins-in-ubuntu).
Basically, you have to configure Jenkins using systemctl by typing

```
systemctl edit jenkins
```

then, pass in:

```
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=<anyPort>"
```