# Issues with Jenkins 1.67 URL set up

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to set a new Jenkins instance (version 1.67) on to a Windows Server 2012 r2.

I am trying to configure a custom URL instead of using

> localhost:8080

etc..

I have set Jenkins URL as

> NewServer.domainname.com

But I cannot access it via that url, I get presented with a message "Remote Web Access is turned off" it only allows me to connect when I follow the URL with the port number;

> NewServer.domainname.com:8080

I am sure that Remote web access is completely different from what my goal is.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Jenkins launches its own built-in webserver, listening on port 8080.

Changing the URL in the Jenkins configuration does not change the port that the running webserver listens on, but rather the URL that is shown within the UI, or in emails sent to users etc.

In order to access Jenkins at just `NewServer.domainname.com` (i.e. running on port 80), you would first have to disable Windows Remote Web Access, which is currently occupying port 80.

You would then need to stop Jenkins and start it again with the flag `--httpPort=80`; these options are documented on the [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins).

If Jenkins was started as a Windows Service, you can edit the `jenkins.xml` file as shown in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23769478/234938).

Comment: hey @Christopher Orr thanks for getting back to me.

I have removed 'Remote Web access' and once i had done that IIS took ownership of that port. 

Now starting Jenkins via command line am getting un able to bind - already in use.

Running 'netstat -ano' I could see that the port was still being used, So currently trying out the answers from - http://superuser.com/questions/352017/pid4-using-port-80

Comment: I suppose IIS is taking ownership of the port, then you would have to disable IIS before starting Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say, after setting Jenkins.xml to run on port `80`, and then via the Jenkins web interface using

> 'install as service'

I found that this process seemed to create a new `jenkins.xml` along with the default `httpPort` which is stored within the `Jenkins.war`.

I get around this I installed as a service, ensured that the service was not set to start on start up. Rebooted the machine

On start up I re-edited the `jenkins.xml` `httpPort` value back to `80`. Started the service and now running very happy!