# Unable to start jenkins war file

Tags: java, ubuntu, jenkins

I'm trying to run jenkins war file, but I'm getting this error:

```
: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
```

This is the command I'm running:

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

This is the full error:

```
Mar 25, 2018 1:55:50 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at Main._main(Main.java:246)
    at Main.main(Main.java:91)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:152)
    ... 7 more

Mar 25, 2018 1:55:51 AM hudson.util.BootFailure publish
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:244)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:267)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:45)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1009)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:877)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:227)
```

I already checked port 8081 and it nothing is running on it.
How to fix it?

Comment: Why did you check port 8081 instead of port 8080?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try on some other port using command

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8089
```

for more info [checkout this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23769478/3892213)

Answer (score 0):

If there is an existing Jenkins instance running (and occupying the default port, say 8080), we would get this error. Shutdown the current running instance and then retry the command. It worked for me.