# Changing the port when running Jenkins Service created via the WAR File

Tags: jenkins

I am running Jenkins from the WAR file on Windows. I came across the option to change the port via the `--httpPort` option, which worked and the instance got launched on my desired port. However when i tried to create the service from the UI it fell back to port 8080.
How can i start Jenkins from the WAR File as a service on other than 8080 port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:-

```
1. Open the Jenkins.xml configuration file and search for string --httpPort=8080
2. Replace the 8080 with the new port.
3. Restart Jenkins for changes to take effect ( you ca also restart Jenkins from the windows services running your machine)
```

Please follow the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769478/how-to-change-port-for-jenkins-window-service-when-8080-is-being-used) for more information.

Comment: while launching from the cmdline it doesn't take the updated `jenkins.xml` file - which i still don't know why rather i need to pass the `--httpPort=<PortNo>` to get it to work.
For the service - when you install the service it resets the configuration file. 
Once the service is installed before starting it, i had to go and redo these values in that file to get it to work. Also the service failed to locate Java for which i had to update the absolute path of java in the executable tag.
and for Java 12.0 i had to append `--enable-future-java` at the end of the command. 
Thanks for the help