# Unable to see Jenkins home page after installing it

Tags: jenkins

I successfully installed Jenkins 2.121.2 on Windows 10 using installer jenkins.msi. After it, opened http://localhost:8080/ which was expecting to open Jenkins home page but rather I can see following message there -

`If you're seeing this, you've successfully installed Tomcat. Congratulations!`

[image]

Can someone please help help what could have been wrong here and what else I need to do?

Comment: You probably have tomcat installed before you installed jenkins  so port 8080 is already taken.

Comment: ` tail -f /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` check the logs, jenkins is not running it tomcate or `java -jar -httpPort=8081 jenkins.war`

Comment: Yes @Shmuel, that is correct. In this case I think Adiii solution will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tail -f /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` check logs to verify the actual issue, seems like tomcat is running on port `8080` as mentioned by @Shmuel

You have two option

- stop the tomcat or [change the tomcat](https://www.neptunelabs.com/fsi-server/changing-port-8080-to-80-using-tomcat/) port to something else then `8080`
- start [Jenkins with other port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769478/how-to-change-port-for-jenkins-window-service-when-8080-is-being-used) then `8080`

```
 java -jar -httpPort=8081 jenkins.war
```