# i could not able to enter in jenkins it struck from login page and i do not have any idea to login?

Tags: jenkins, wmi

i am totally confused about jenkins login.
About my system:
RAM...4gb,
system type...64 bit,
processor... pentium.
i was executing all codes successfully in these languages (SQL plus, java, hibernate, spring boot, angular)
1 fine day one of my mate asked my laptop to install jenkins and i gave it to her.
when i get it from her i got shocked.

THE PROBLEM STARTS:
SQLplus is not working and port no 8080 is occupied by jenkins.
but i cant login and i asked her. she told that i also face the same issue and when i install it the page comes like this to me only.... but i know that i did not before install it before.

from command prompt jenkins location if i try start command it shows following error:

If I start service with "WinSW.NET4.exe start" I got:
2017-04-21 11:35:01,236 INFO - Starting ServiceWrapper in the CLI mode 2017-04-21 11:35:01,518 FATAL - WMI Operation failure: AccessDenied WMI.WmiException: AccessDenied at WMI.WmiRoot.BaseHandler.CheckError(ManagementBaseObject result) at WMI.WmiRoot.InstanceHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args) at winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] _args, ServiceDescriptor descriptor) at winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)

i strucked here from 4 days any one help me to install it or uninstall it...

Comment: Can you please be more clear what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: for my system configuration can i install jenkins? will it support or not? if it supports i would like to install it. already it occupied localhost:8080 so, installation not possible means i am ready to uninstall it... some one help me to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run Jenkins on your system but 4GB of memory can get tight if you have other servers like Tomcat or a local database running in parallel. To make it work you just have to change the port Jenkins is running on to avoid conflicts.

See [How to change port for jenkins window service when 8080 is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769478/how-to-change-port-for-jenkins-window-service-when-8080-is-being-used) or the official documentation [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS//Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) for details.

Comment: i got what u told and i have tomcat also but i dont know the steps to run it.... can anyone help me out for this issue

Comment: You need to change the port for Jenkins to something else (eg 8081) as described in the StackOverflow link above.