# Jenkins Start up issue (hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: java.lang.Error: Failed to load the key: hudson. util.Secret)

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Hi I wanted to integrate my selenium automation framework from bitbucket to Jenkins . I have installed **jenkins-2.107.2(jenkins.msi)** , after that i **downloaded jenkins war(2.116)** file and tried to execute 
from **command prompt (java -jar jenkins.war)** from the respective path where war file is present

**but in cmd prompt i get below error.**

```
enter code here
```

C:\Jenkins>java -jar jenkins.war

**Have copied and pasted only the error part from cmd prompt**

```
←[31mApr 12, 2018 5:50:54 PM hudson.util.BootFailure publishSEVERE: Failedto initialize Jenkinshudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: java.lang.Error: Failed toloadthe key: hudson.util.Secret
```

**While lauching localhost http://localhost:8080/ i get the below error**

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\SSUSEEL\.jenkins\secrets\hudson.util.Secret
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at jenkins.security.DefaultConfidentialStore.store(DefaultConfidentialStore.java:79)
at jenkins.security.ConfidentialKey.store(ConfidentialKey.java:51)
at jenkins.security.CryptoConfidentialKey.getKey(CryptoConfidentialKey.java:44)

Caused: java.lang.Error: Failed to load the key: hudson.util.Secret
    at jenkins.security.CryptoConfidentialKey.getKey(CryptoConfidentialKey.java:53)
    at jenkins.security.CryptoConfidentialKey.decrypt(CryptoConfidentialKey.java:134)
    at hudson.util.HistoricalSecrets.decrypt(HistoricalSecrets.java:49)
    at hudson.util.Secret.decrypt(Secret.java:207)
    at hudson.util.Secret.fromString(Secret.java:249)
    at jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty.<init>(ApiTokenProperty.java:86)
    at jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty$DescriptorImpl.newInstance(ApiTokenProperty.java:179)
    at jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty$DescriptorImpl.newInstance(ApiTokenProperty.java:164)
    at hudson.model.User.load(User.java:209)
    at hudson.model.User.<init>(User.java:161)
    at hudson.model.User.getOrCreate(User.java:531)
    at hudson.model.User.getOrCreate(User.java:479)
    at hudson.model.User.getById(User.java:636)
    at hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm.createAccount(HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm.java:406)
    at jenkins.install.SetupWizard.init(SetupWizard.java:110)
    at jenkins.install.InstallState$4.initializeState(InstallState.java:110)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.setInstallState(Jenkins.java:1035)
    at jenkins.install.InstallUtil.proceedToNextStateFrom(InstallUtil.java:97)
    at jenkins.install.InstallState$1.initializeState(InstallState.java:55)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:923)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:233)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:24
```

Can some one help me .. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You have not written what is your OS, I assume it is Windows because you have downloaded msi file.

I would stick to the current LTS version 2.107.2 and the msi. The msi should have installed the Jenkins master as [Windows service](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Thanks+for+using+Windows+Installer). I would not attempt to use the war file 2.116 on Windows. It is currently not the LTS version and could be not stable enough. 
This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869311/start-stop-and-restart-jenkins-service-on-windows) can help you.