# When selenium test runs by Jenkins and nUnit, the browser doesn't come up however there are valid results

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I would say that my problem rather lack of information and I need some confirmation than a real problem. It seems somebody else had similar question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787682/unable-to-see-selenium-tests-are-running-on-the-browser-when-the-test-is-run-by).

I put together a machine (Windows Server 2012R2) for POC reasons where a Jenkins installed and it executes Selenium UI tests using [nunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121312/how-do-you-run-nunit-tests-from-jenkins). The nunit tests are generated by Specflow.

I could do:

- install jenkins
- jenkins run by a valid user not by Service account
- set up jenkins properly
- it can pull the source code from TFS-GIT
- it can compile the C# solution
- it can execute the test project
- the test results are correct

Selenium plugin installed on Jenkins but I don't think it is used in this case because the text execution is about executing nunit and it deals with everything else.

At the moment I don't need the capability to delegate test execution to other Jenkins slaves or machines because the Jenkins does have only one compile task. Compiling, executing and test running can go parallel, the machine able to deal with it.

But, when I log in the server where the Jenkins runs and I watch what happens during CI build (compile and test execution) I can't see that the browser (Firefox) starts, however, the test results and the logs show that a browser was executed.

What I did so far:

- jenkins runs as service, the account is an existing account

If I remote to the machine with the account which is set up for the service, then I can't see  the browser will be executed, however, the log shows that something had happened.

My question is that, what the hack is happening when my tests are executed by Jenkins? If I execute the command which is used by Jenkins from console on the same machine then I can see that Firefox starts, does what is programmed in the tests and the results are in the result.xml. Can I accept the result as valid result? Can I somehow set up Jenkins the way the browser really executed (I can believe it when I see it :) )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you run Jenkins as a service. Services do not show up in desktop. Workaround is to run Jenkins or slave from CMD.

[Jenkins windows slave service does not interact with desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906753/jenkins-windows-slave-service-does-not-interact-with-desktop)